# How to find if SORTKEY is defined and how it is defined from catalog tables?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am creating a view for generating the DDLs for the tables. I am stuck at a point where I am unable to find how the SORTKEY is defined like SORTKEY AUTO or SORTKEY(columns).
I saw there is a column "attsortkeyord" in the pg_attribute table but it gives numerical values which only tell the order of columns defined in sort keys.
There is a system view named "svv_table_info" which has column "sortkey1". This actually tells what exactly I required like AUTO(EVEN) or AUTO(ALL) but this view I am unable to use with other queries inside my main view.
Whenever I use "svv_table_info" I get an error *"Function not supported"* for almost all functions like text, format_type, etc.
Can anyone please help me either how to get details from catalog tables or how to deal with this error while using "svv_table_info"?

Comment: Here is a view for generating DDL: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_tbl_ddl.sql

Comment: @dfundako: I took the help of this project only but in this, it will generate SORTKEY statement only if custom columns are defined and it will tell if they are INTERLEAVED or not.
I am looking for the statements like "SORTKEY AUTO".